# Get the vertex_id variable in a NVIDIA CG vertex shader to create Index Map

Tags: opengl, glsl, nvidia, cg

I need to generate an Index Map (Index list) containing the id of each projected vertex. My shader code is based on NVIDIA CG 3.0 and I can't find in the documentation the build-in variable name to extract the id of each vertex.

In GLSL is something like: gl_VertexID. What is the equivalent in CG? If is not accessible, can you think of other way of generating an Index Map that doesn't involve extra storage?

Answer (score 0):

CG uses semantic binding as in [HLSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I think the semantic is `VERTEXID`, if you can't find an example in your CG toolkit, look in directx examples for `SV_VertexID` and follow a similar syntax for CG `VERTEXID`.